# Integrating Azure AD into a Java web application

Tags: azure, adal

I am new to Azure and OpenIDConnect. To start with, I cloned the sample git Application and tried to test it. It's giving me the below error. The War has the oauth2 jar and I can see the class files present there.

Git URL: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter BasicFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/openid/connect/sdk/AuthenticationSuccessResponse
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.processAnnotations(DefaultInstanceManager.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.AuthenticationSuccessResponse
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error information, it seems that the [`oauth2-oidc-sdk`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/4.5) dependency defined in the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/blob/master/pom.xml#L20) file of the sample project had not been installed.

1. Try to command `mvn install` to download the dependency for the project.
2. Try to check the environment variable `M2_HOME` whether be defined for your environment or your IDE.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the oauth-oidc-sdk.jar and gson.jar in the tomcat lib. The application is working.