# NoClassDefFoundError while deploying a OpenID Azure AD java web-app on Weblogic

Tags: java, azure, weblogic, adal

I am trying to integrate Azure AD for my web-app using OpenIDConnect approach. When I try to deploy the built ear file on weblogic I get NoClassDefFound for

> com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.AuthenticationSuccessResponse

. I have included **oauth2-oidc-sdk-5.24.1.jar** in the web-inf/lib folder, also verified that it is actually present within the ear file yet the application deployment fails complaining it is not able to find this class.

I found similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006441/integrating-azure-ad-into-a-java-web-application). So I tried deploying both oauth2-oidc-sdk-5.24.1.jar and gson jar file as a library along with my java web app, but that did not help as well.

Much appreciated if I can get any pointers or suggestions to overcome this error.

The full stacktrace during deployment:

```
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/openid/connect/sdk/AuthenticationSuccessResponse
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1793)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getMethods(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1055)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getMethods(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1043)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:99)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:37)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processFilters(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:239)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:210)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:105)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1370)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:450)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:59)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
```

#####################################

Update 2021/06/02

To resolve the version compatibility issue, I had to opt below specific versions of dependencies to get it not throw the error for JDK1.6, and microsoft adal4j had to recompiled in JDK6 (adal4j jar is supported on jdk1.7 and above)

```
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
    <version>5.9</version>
    

    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
    <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
    <version>5.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

If the JDK is 1.7, below is the specific versions that worked for me:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>5.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>7.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope this helps someone facing similar error on JDK1.6 and JDK1.7

Comment: I had similar issue, and fixed it by downgrading spring from 2.4.4 to 2.2.4.

Comment: Is the comment above helpful?

Comment: @AllenWu:  It was about version compatibility. I have updated the question with versions that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by incompatible versions. You can try different versions of `oauth2-oidc-sdk` until you find a compatible package.

Or you can also change the version of `spring` to achieve the purpose of version compatibility as mentioned in the comments.